# Subclassing tab control

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing

What is the proper way to subclass a tab control in winAPI, having windows perform both the default drawing and your own. Because BeginPaint() and EndPaint() are calling within the default proc, I don't see a way to do this. I did get it working with GetDC(), but it had a very bugs which annoyed the hell out of me.

If what I am asking is impossible, what is the best way to draw the tabs by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing is not required in your situation. The tab control supports the [TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760549%28VS.85%29.aspx) style bit, which allows its parent window to handle [WM_DRAWITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775923%28VS.85%29.aspx) messages and draw the tabs itself.

There's [a nice exemple](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/tabcontrols/article.php/c2237) on Codeguru. It uses MFC but don't let that stop you. Check out their `CTabCtrlEx::DrawItem()` method.

Comment: This is the reverse of what I want. I need to draw the background myself, and let windows do the tabs.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear in your question (especially the last line). Did you try handling [WM_ERASEBKGND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648055%28VS.85%29.aspx) then?

Comment: The link is dead - 404